# Torch turns off when I change the device orientation

Tags: ios, swift

I have a test project because I'm just trying to learn swift. So I wanted to try to do something with the torch, I made just a simple button to turn the torch on/off but I found out that when I change the device orientation it turns off the torch. And I was wondering if anyone had the same problem and found a solution so they can keep the torch on while changing screen orientation.

This is the code for the torch I found it on https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/how-to-turn-on-the-camera-flashlight-to-make-a-torch

```
   func toggleTorch(on: Bool)
{
    guard let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else {return}
    
    if device.hasTorch
    {
        do
        {
            try device.lockForConfiguration()
            
            if on
            {
                device.torchMode = .on
            } else
            {
                device.torchMode = .off
            }
            
            device.unlockForConfiguration()
        } catch
        {
            print("Torch could not be used")
        }
    } else
    {
        print("Torch is not available")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary fix. I have to use setTorchMode then adjust the level argument lower so it doesn't overheat and turn off. It still turns off but its on for a little longer than before